# backbone js - Dynamic loading view: should el be the launcher, or should it be launched by a parent view?

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js

I have a question about the el tag on a dynamically loading view element.  I'm attaching a click listener to an `<a>` tag, which will dynamically load the view element (render it from a template, populate some content over ajax etc.).  Now I have currently implemented it as follows:

```
MyDynamicView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "a#dynamic-launcher",
    events: {
        "click": "launch"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
    },
    launch: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
                    // do template/ajax/whatever.
    }
});
```

Which works fairly well, but it does preclude me from doing some things.  For example, if I wanted to add another event, which was triggered by something from within my new dynamic view, I couldn't do that (since the events only look below the parent `el`).

So an alternative might be to have a parent view, which knows about what element launches the dynamic element, and then creates/renders it.

```
velo.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "body",
    events: {
        "click a#dynamic-launcher": "launchDynamicView"
    },
    launchDynamicView: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        new MyDynamicView(); // Or something - Maybe I need to call render.  Not sure.
    }
});
```

Does this second technique make more sense?

Any guidance would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to have

```
MyDynamicView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "div",
    events: {
        "click a#dynamic launcher": "launch"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        el.append($("<a></a>", {
            id: "#dynamic-launcher"
        }));
    },
    launch: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        // render link again?
        // do template/ajax/whatever.
    }
});
```

Your view should *contain* the link, not *be* the link.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for though - The link which launches the view may be in a completely different part of the page from what the view eventually renders.  The link ought to have been rendered before the view is rendered.

Comment: @idbentley Ah. Then you'll need to attach some kind of `Controller` to hook up the link/button with generating a new `View` object somewhere. Feels like a `View` -> `Controller` -> `View` relation rather then `ParentView` -> `ChildView`

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be using backbone Views as intended. You're binding an event to a#dynamic-launcher, but this element is not part of the view in which this event binding is defined. Your second attempt with the AppView is better.

Of course, implementation depends on the goals of your app, but perhaps something like this is what you need:

An initial starting html page skeleton:

```
<html>
      <head><!-- include your javascript --></head>
      <body></body>
</html>
```

An App View

```
AppView
     events: {
         "click a#dynamiclauncher" : "launch"
     }
     render: function(){
        $('body').html $(el).html(this.template())
     }
     launch: function(){
        $(el).find('.dynamic-view-location').html new DynamicView.render().el
     }
```

A corresponding AppTemplate

```
<p>
   Hello world
   <a id="dynamic-launcher">Launch Dynamic View</a>
   <div class=".dynamic-view-location"></div>
</p>
```

A Dynamic View

```
DynamicView
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template())
    }
```

A Corresponding Dynamic View Template

Comment: This is essentially what I am doing in the second case, except that I want to build the dynamic view from a template at launch time, not at render time.  I'd also point out that you can use `this.$('selector')` to select relative to the current view (rather than `$(el).find(selector)`.  I agree that this is more correct than what I initially proposed, but I don't see what it adds to my second proposal.

Comment: Launch time for the AppView, is render time for the Dynamic View. The the html for the dynamic view will not be generated until that link is clicked!

Comment: thanks for the tip on this.$('selector'). Will be using that one in future!